# How to add Comma for total in the gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

Do anyone know how to give comma for the calculated total value displaying in grid view Footer in asp.net c#?

Eg:12,492,323

Comment: How do you arrive/compute the Total ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void grdList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal"));
        lbl.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", Total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without code posted, it is hard to answer your question precisely.

Assuming in your code behind you calculate the total, instead of putting in the total as `total.ToString()`, use `total.ToString("N0")` instead.